# Third-party function overrides my customized variable and my mode hook

Tags: spacemacs, hooks, company-mode

In the spacemace python layer, the following function overrides my customizations for the variable `company-minimum-prefix-length`
[python layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b86a074437503677d21e2172bd175b37edbdb029/layers/%2Blang/python/packages.el#L109)

```
(defun python/post-init-company ()
  ;; backend specific
  (add-hook 'python-mode-local-vars-hook #'spacemacs//python-setup-company)
  (spacemacs|add-company-backends
    :backends (company-files company-capf)
    :modes inferior-python-mode
    :variables
    company-minimum-prefix-length 0
    company-idle-delay 0.5)
  (when (configuration-layer/package-used-p 'pip-requirements)
    (spacemacs|add-company-backends
      :backends company-capf
      :modes pip-requirements-mode)))
```

I've tried setting this variable to 2 with a mode hook as well as by using `M-x customize`

This hook in my init file has zero effect (maybe I'm doing something wrong):

```
  (add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq-local company-minimum-prefix-length 2)))
```

`M-x customize-variable` also has zero effect in the python buffer although it works in other buffers. After save and apply in the customize-variable buffer `M-x describe-variable` yields this:

```
Its value is 0
Original value was 3
Local in buffer *Python*; global value is 2

The minimum prefix length for idle completion.

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  You can customize this variable.

[back]
```

The only way I can change the variable is by using `M-x set-variable` after the buffer loads. This change is overridden if I restart the buffer with `M-x python-shell-restart`. Is there any way I can write a hook that will set the variable after all other mode hooks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto completion popup opens with zero character match in Inferior Python mode (comint repl)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78581/auto-completion-popup-opens-with-zero-character-match-in-inferior-python-mode-c)

Comment: Sorry, no. That question that led me to post this question.  I'm looking for a hook or something that will run automatically so I don't have to manually type `M-x set-variable` every time I open an inferior-python buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a hook on `company-mode` instead of `inferior-python-mode` worked presumably due to the order in which the modes run.

```
  (add-hook 'company-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (if
                  (equal major-mode 'inferior-python-mode)
                  (setq-local company-minimum-prefix-length 2))))
```